# Check that no input arguments are empty in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function with about 10 input arguments. After data processing, these arguments can be empty arrays/vectors. In this event, I would like to set each output to 0 and exit(return) from the function.

How can I do a check to make sure that all inputs to a function are nonempty, without having to type each of them out. I would like something like.

```
function [outputs1and2] = myfunct(many_arguments)
if isempty(any_input_argument)
    out1 = 0;
    out2 = 0;
    return
end
out1 = some_math;
out2 = more_math;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of [`varargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) to initially hold all of your input arguments in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), which you can easily check using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
function [out1, out2] = myfunct(varargin)
  if any(cellfun(@isempty, varargin))
    out1 = 0;
    out2 = 0;
    return
  end
  % ...further processing
end
```

And when you need to use an input argument for subsequent processing, you can just extract it from `varargin` like so:

```
in1 = varargin{1};  % Get first input argument
```

In addition, although it may be more involved than what you're looking for, you can also check out [`inputParser` objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html) for validating input arguments to your function.

Comment: I see this as a possibility, though having to later do varargin{} for each of the inputs makes it about the same amount of lines. Ill probably just specify isempty for each one. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Leo: You don't *have* to place every value in `varargin` into a new variable. You can just use, for example, `varargin{1}` in place of every usage of `in1`, or whatever you had previously called your first input variable.